# Import Error starting Celery worker

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am getting the following error when I start a celery worker using the `celery worker` command. The Django project otherwise seems to be running alright.

```
$ celery -A testproj worker -l info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 306, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 269, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 212, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 128, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 116, in import_default_modules
    signals.import_modules.send(sender=self.app)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 42, in __call__
    self.set_error_state(exc)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 39, in __call__
    **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs) if self.kwargs else kwargs
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 327, in _autodiscover_tasks
    self.loader.autodiscover_tasks(packages, related_name)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 251, in autodiscover_tasks
    related_name) if mod)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 272, in autodiscover_tasks
    return [find_related_module(pkg, related_name) for pkg in packages]
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 282, in find_related_module
    pkg_path = importlib.import_module(package).__path__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    install_cacheops()
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 571, in install_cacheops
    for model in get_models(include_auto_created=True):
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 232, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 97, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/Users/devang/virtualenvs/testproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named accounts
```

My installed apps looks like-
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cacheops',
    'accounts',
    )

I have installed the celery project in Django as suggested in the link http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. My Django project structure did not follow the default structure of-

`--proj
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
--accounts
    |--__init__.py
--app2
    |-- __init__.py`

Instead if followed:

`--proj
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- apps
         |--accounts
             |--__init__.py
         |--app2
             |-- __init__.py`

which was causing Celery to find the module.

Comment: Please elaborate what you did to solve it, as I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I changed my project structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems I was having a different issue, celery would not use my virtualenv. So I ended up using python3.4 -m celery worker. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have such a structure you can 'hack' it this way:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('apps'))
```

before setting

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
```

It worked for me. Of course you have to adjust the path in `sys.path` to your project structure.